# Specifying LINEST output in EXCEL

Tags: arrays, excel

Excel LINEST function returns an array of outputs (statistic) such as se1, se2, r2, ssresid, etc. I am interested in getting only the ssresid output in one cell. My idea is following:

=CHOOSE(10, LINEST(y,x,,TRUE))

however this does not work. Internet search does not help, but I believe the problem is with my manipulation of the LINEST output array. Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong in the equation, and possibly explain how it works with arrays in this kind of setting (array obtained by function)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linest returns a matrix.  The matrix is n wide x 5 high where n is the number of dependent variables.   The format of the output is:

https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/e0d97b28-95d9-4cb2-888c-78db54378381.gif

Ssresid is in the fifth row, second column.  To isolate it, do some matrix math:  Eg if n=3 enter the following matrix in cells X21:Z25 or (anywhere else you please.)

```
      X Y Z
 21 0 0 0
 22 0 0 0
 23 0 0 0
 24 0 0 0
 25 0 1 0
```

Then enter 
{= sum(LINEST(y,x,,TRUE) * x21:z25) }
When you enter the formula be sure to press Ctrl shift enter.  This tells excel to evaluate the formula as a matrix formula.